# Python DataFrame Merging

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I need to merge two dataframes. I create several of the below dataframe from reading files.

What i need to do is pull the 'Depth' column and insert it into a new dataframe. I will then rename the column 'Depth' in the merged dataframe to the serial number of that part. Then repeat.

sigData example

```
  Current  Depth  Time Velocity
0     130  11066   0.1    26516
1     150  13716   0.2    24090
2     153  15995   0.3    25052
3     157  19109   0.4    26596
4     160  20298   0.5    19947
```

The resulting dataframe after looping through all 'sigData' files should look like this:

depthDF example

```
     Time    Sn1     Sn2      Sn3
0     0.1  11066   00001    00001
1     0.2  13716   00002    00002
2     0.3  15995   00003    00003
3     0.4  19109   00004    00004
4     0.5  20298   00005    00005
```

I will do the same with 'Current' and 'Velocity'. The result should be three dataframes. One with the 'Depth' of all parts, one with 'Velocity' of all parts, and one with 'Current' of all parts.

```
velocityDF = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Time'])
velocityDF = velocityDF.join(sigData['Velocity'], on='Time', sort='True')
velocityDF.rename(columns={'Velocity': row['SerialNumber']}, inplace=True)
```

results in:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Time, 400602902, 400621787, 400621434, 400619512]
Index: []
```

and

```
depthDF = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Time'])
depthDF = depthDF.merge(sigData['Depth'], on='Time', sort='True')
depthDF.rename(columns={'Depth': row['SerialNumber']}, inplace=True)
```

results in:

```
ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
depthDF = depthDF.merge(sigData[['Depth','Time']], on='Time', sort='True', how='right')
```

Same do for velocityDF.

Hope it helps and will resolve your error..

Comment: KeyError: 'Time'     It looks like it only pulled the 'Depth' column so it did not have a key to use for the merge

Comment: Try `depthDF = depthDF.merge(sigData[['Depth','Time']], on='Time', sort='True')`

Comment: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'    i cant seem to find a way to pull two columns from a dataframe by column name and not column number ex(print(sigData[['Depth','Time']].head()))

Comment: For that you have to use  `.loc`. Try to pull with `print(sigData.loc[ : , 'Depth':'Time'].head())`.

Comment: Yeah that does work, it returns the two columns and data but `depthDF = depthDF.merge(sigData.loc[:,['Depth','Time']], on='Time', sort='True')`  Still returns: `Empty DataFrame
Columns: [400602902, 400621787, 400621434, 400619512, Time]
Index: []`

Comment: How are you getting serial numbers for particular value of depth. Is it stored in another DF??

Comment: I am wondering if my problem is that the depthDF dataframe does not start with values in the 'Time' column therefor no data is getting merged

Comment: `for index, row in df.iterrows():
        sigData = readSignature(row['FullPath'])    
depthDF = depthDF.merge(sigData.loc[:,['Depth','Time']], on='Time', sort='True')
        
depthDF.rename(columns={'Depth': row['SerialNumber']}, inplace=True)`

Comment: I have a dataframe with the filepath and serial number for all of the parts i am pulling data for. I then loop through that, pull the data, and add the columns to their respective dataframes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213801/discussion-between-mohd-bilal-and-maxwell).